# Using multiple openmp host threads and opencl

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, opencl, openmp

My GPU is a ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5450; specifications for the 5470 (which are nearly identical) can be found [here](https://compubench.com/device-environment.jsp?config=12278593). I've encountered a problem using multiple host threads (using OpenMP) and OpenCL. What I'm doing is the following:

I've got one instance of the following class containing the context, program, queue, etc.:

```
class OclMain
{
    ...
    ...
    cl::Device       device;
    cl::Context      context;
    cl::CommandQueue queue;
    cl::Program      program;
    cl::Program::Sources sources;
    ...
    ...
}
```

For each OpenMP thread I have an instance of the following class, which each contains its own cl::Kernel because setArg(...) isn't thread safe. Each of these also handles its own buffer creation, execution of the kernel, etc. If, for example, I have a maximum of 16 threads using #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(16), I create 16 of these objects and each thread has its own Ocl object. When a thread is done, the Ocl object is reused for a next iteration of the aforementioned for loop and setEpi() is called again to upload the new data to the device. Each thread handles one cv::Mat epi.

```
class Ocl
{
    Ocl(OclMain *oclm) : oclm(oclm) { kernel = cl::Kernel(oclg->program,"kernel"); }
    ...
    // this data doesn't change during execution of an openmp thread, so I only upload it once to the device after thread creation
    void setEpi(cv::Mat &epi)
    {
        ...
        img_epi = cl::Image2D(oclm->context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, cl::ImageFormat(CL_RGBA, CL_FLOAT), epi.cols, epi.rows, 0, 0);

        cl::size_t<3> origin;
        origin[0] = 0; origin[1] = 0, origin[2] = 0;
        cl::size_t<3> region;
        region[0] = epi.cols; region[1] = epi.rows; region[2] = 1;

        oclg->queue.enqueueWriteImage(img_epi, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, epi.data, 0, 0);
        ...

        // enqueue some more WriteBuffers here (only small buffers)
        ...
            ...
    }
    ...
    // gets called multiple times (maximum epi.rows times, on a row per row basis; 
    // the algorithm I need to implement works this way)
    void runKernel(...)
    {
        // will contain result of kernel computation
        cl::Buffer buff(oclg->context,CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,sizeof(float)*dmax*epi.cols);

        // set kernel args here
        // ...

        // enqueue kernel
        oclg->queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, cl::NDRange(epi.cols/64*64+64),cl::NDRange(64));

        // get results from device
        oclg->queue.enqueueReadBuffer(buffer,CL_TRUE,0,sizeof(float)*dmax*epi.cols,result.data());      
    }

    ...
    ...
    cl::Kernel  kernel;
    OclMain    *oclm
    cl::Image2D img_epi

}
```

If epi.rows and epi.cols is small (e.g.: 240x100) this works without a problem.
If epi.rows and epi.cols is big(ger) (e.g.: 863x100), it does not, unless I only use ONE OpenMP thread. If I use more threads, the program will freeze after executing the first few threads. As far as radeontop is concerned; at this point there is nothing going on on the GPU, 0% for all statistics.

The problem seems to be that the call to oclg->queue.enqueueWriteImage(img_epi, CL_TRUE, origin, region, 0, 0, epi.data, 0, NULL) never finishes. If I change the call to non-blocking, the program continues running, untill the next blocking call which won't return either.

I tried flushing; didn't help much either. HOWEVER, I don't seem to have this problem if I upload the data using the CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR method instead of enqueueing a WriteImage. What's going on?

Comment: 16 Contexts and Commans queues for one Device is overkill in my opinion, and big issue to driver, which has to handle all of them.

Your Device can execute one OpenCL kernel at a time, so by launching kernels, you are actually serializing your application, which makes all OpenMP code merely useless. Does your code works correct with single thread?

Comment: I am only using 1 context and 1 command queue, that's what the OclMain class is for, of which there is only 1 instance. The 16 Ocl objects all use this 1 OclMain instance (oclm->queue) to queue. I am sorry if this was unclear. The code is working correctly with a single thread, as well as with multiple threads (i.e.: with epi small or CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR).

Comment: What version of AMD APP SDK and OpenCL do you have?

Comment: Platform Version: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1214.3). Installed using AMD-APP-SDK-v2.9-lnx64 iirc.

Comment: Unless you need the host threads for other processing, they aren't making your OpenCL any faster, so remove them if you can.

Comment: E.g.: 1 thread = 24seconds, 16 threads = 14seconds. So it does cause some speedup. But the host threads are indeed also used to do some other processing, processing which includes quite some branching/loops/etc. which means I can't move it over to the GPU. Well, not without running inefficiently, I think.

Comment: It appears that if I add a "std::mutex mtx" to the OclMain class, and put a oclm->mtx.lock() and oclm->mtx.unlock() at the top and bottom of Ocl::setEpi() and Ocl::runKernel(), the program runs without a problem. I hereby serialize the enqueueing of kernels and writes/reads, but according to both of you enqueueing in parallel doesn't offer any benefit anyway, so it doesn't matter much; the other processing on the host threads still can be done in parallel this way. This makes me wonder though: according to the specification of OpenCL 1.2, enqueueing should be thread-safe. It appears it is not?

Comment: Section "A.2 Multiple Host Threads" of the OpenCL 1.1 specification sys "All OpenCL API calls are thread-safe except `clSetKernelArg`. `clSetKernelArg` is safe to call from any host thread, and is safe to call re-entrantly so long as concurrent calls operate on
different cl_kernel objects. However, the behavior of the cl_kernel object is undefined if `clSetKernelArg` is called from multiple host threads on the same cl_kernel object at the same time." That said, it might be safer to lock around all `clSetKernelArg` to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel` blocks.